# How to slow hover buttons and align them in specific location

Tags: html, css

EDIT: I need when you hover , it slowly appears blue, not instantly. 
Here is the css:

```
.button {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:40px 40px;
    border:none;
    font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#392a23;
    background-color:#a2a2a2;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#464646', endColorstr='#464646', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #909090;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#909090, offx=0, offy=2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.button {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:40px 40px;
    border:none;
    font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#392a23;
    background-color:#a2a2a2;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#464646', endColorstr='#464646', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2 0%, #464646 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #909090;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#909090, offx=0, offy=2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover {
    padding:40px 40px;
    border:none;
    font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#372d2f;
    background-color:#00aeff;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom, #00aeff 0%, #000e4a 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom, #00aeff 0%, #000e4a 100%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(bottom, #00aeff 0%, #000e4a 100%);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(bottom, #00aeff 0%, #000e4a 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000e4a', endColorstr='#000e4a', GradientType=0);
    background-image: radial-gradient(bottom, #00aeff 0%, #000e4a 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #3098d9;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#3098d9, offx=0, offy=2);
}
.button:active {
    padding:40px 40px;
    border:none;
    font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#313131;
    background:#606060;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px -20px #bababa, inset 0px 0px -20px #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #777777;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#777777, offx=0, offy=2);
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Home</a> 
<a href="#" class="button">Games</a>
```

I tried `transition: all 500ms linear; transition-delay: 1ms;` and `-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out`

but none make a delay or a slow hover. It is not working!
The slow hover is the only problem now.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? From your code, they look like they are aligned properly: http://jsfiddle.net/0krfzfbr/

Comment: I don't see what is not pixel perfect to you. To me they seem alright. They are aligned vertically..

Comment: Working with this fiddle - jsfiddle.net/0krfzfbr - I just modified the html to look like this: <a href="#" class="button">Home</a><a href="#" class="button">Games</a> (no new line between the buttons) and they touch now.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to move the whole menu of buttons to the right? :P

Comment: <div class="myclass">
<a href="#" class="button">Home</a><a href="#" class="button">Games</a>
</div>  and the css for that : 
.myclass {
    margin-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

Comment: How do you fix the slow hover effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're searching for, and also on your markup. Anyway, the 2 main alternatives I would use are:

a. make them inline-block (if they're block or inline elements) and then eventually apply vertical-align:middle, if you need to.

```
.button{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

b. make them block or inline-block elements and float all left. In this case you could need to also add some clearfix styles on the contaner, ora add a clearfix div before/after the buttons. Again, if you'll even provide your markup and a more detaild description of what you need, we can help more and be more specific.

```
.button{
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: I got them to touch, with the float, but how do you move the menu around?

Comment: what would you like to achieve? It all depends on what you exactly want. Also, you really should edit your question adding your current html markup, because it also depends on what elements are implied.

Comment: I finished everything except for figuring out how to make the background-image animated, or something. I have seen it.

Comment: I want the background color to be animated.

Comment: Look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150552/transition-all-500ms-ease-in-out-is-not-working-with-background-of-a-button?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you further if you don't provide visual examples and the html markup.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the white-space issue when lining up inline-blocks, a common fix is to give the parent element `font-size: 0;` and reset the font-size to whatever you need for your lined-up inline-blocks.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6j3ezt3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gap between the buttons and wrap them inside a DIV with the following CSS

```
<div id="posbuttons">
   <a href="#" class="button">Home</a><a href="#" class="button">Games</a>
</div>

#posbuttons{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    top:40px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

jsfiddle for demo : http://jsfiddle.net/0krfzfbr/1/

Comment: Thanks, how do you move it right more without making the bottom scroll bar appear?

Comment: you could change margin:auto; to margin-left:50%;